# How to create new objects via ajax that don't yet have a persisted association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `Post` class which `has_many: :widgets`.

On this post editor page, a user can add widgets to the post (a video, image, tweet, html block), and then save the post.

I was originally going to use `nested_attributes_for`, but there are several reasons I don't want to do that.

Instead, I have opted to use ajax to create widgets in real time.

This is a pseudo-explanation of my ideal workflow that I'm trying to achieve:

1. User clicks "New Post" on frontend, and on the backend a `Post.new` is instantiated
2. User clicks a button that says `add tweet widget`, and ajax calls an endpoint which calls `Widget.create(widget_params)`
3. User continues to add widgets.
4. User saves the post, and `@post` becomes persisted.
5. All the widgets that where added to the post get properly assigned to the post
6. If the user exits the page before saving, the old widgets get cleaned up by a background job

The problem is that I need to make it so that during widget creation, each widget is assigned to a Post that hasn't been persisted yet.

I realize one option is to `create` a new Post every time you hit 'new post', and then clean up all the dead ones via a background job, but I don't want to do that for a few reasons.

I watched a [Railscast video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments) about nested attributes, which looks like he's doing something similar (by generating a random ID or something, and then using `object_id` of the new object), but I don't understand it will enough (or at all) to implement it on what I'm currently trying to do.

Any explanation of how to do this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why you don't want use nested attributes?

Comment: Take a look at the cocoon gem. It makes building dynamic Ajax forms like this fairly easy. Then you can just save the post and then save the widgets. If the user exits neither are persisted and no background job is needed.

Comment: Does coccoon work with STI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create widgets and pass their ID's back via ajax, and store them in some hidden field. After User saves his post, you assign those widgets newly created post_id.
Note: You should probably associate widgets with the user, just in case someone tries adding values to those hidden fields manually.
Just an idea.